# Bootstrap twitter like follow button

Tags: javascript, css, button, twitter-bootstrap

I need to a a following button like [this example](http://demo.techumber.com/demo?of=TwitterLikeFUF/&backto=http://www.techumber.com/2012/10/create-twitter-like-follow-and-unfollow.html&title=Create%20Twitter%20Like%20Follow%20And%20Unfollow%20With%20Jquery)

What i should write in java script?

```
  $('.following').hover(function(){
      $(this).text("Unfollow");
    },function(){
       $(this).text("Following");
    });
   //for toggle the class following/follow When click
   $('.following').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('following follow').unbind("hover");
    if($(this).is('.follow')){
       $(this).text("Follow");
    }
    else{
     //binding mouse hover functionality
       $(this).bind({
            mouseleave:function(){$(this).text("Following");},
            mouseenter:function(){$(this).text("Unfollow");}      
        });
    }
  });
```

what changes need to have bootstap button?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in CSS like so: http://jsfiddle.net/Th4th/

```
.follow {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: gray;
}
.follow:hover span {display:none;}

.follow:hover:before {
    content: "Unfollow"
}
```

I don't think you'll need java script for the button changing, only for taking the action of the click.

Comment: I want use bootstap clasess